Usage of こんなもんて in this sentence?

The context is the following: A streamed made use of a service but the service was ineffective and he's complain he wasted money.
So I understand the last sentence is akin to "I paid a lot of money but it was a huge waste!" but I don't quite get, what's こんなもんて here?

って usually gets changed to て following ん.

この金額払ってこんなもん is a sentence wrapped in quotative (っ)て. こんなもん literally means "this thing" but it is better understood as "it became like this" here.

この金額払ってこんなもんて正直金の無駄遣いすぎましたね
Honestly, we wasted too much money. I thought "we paid this amount of money and this is how it turned out?!?"

I admit that it is difficult to translate this sentence but I hope you get the idea.
